# Ordering timeouts in JS

Tags: javascript, timeout

If I want to execute multiple timeouts one after another in which way can it be accomplished?
if I have:

```
setTimeout('one', 6000);
setTimeout('two', 500);
setTimeout('three', 4000);
setTimeout('four', 2000);
```

it'll be executed in this order: two -> four -> three -> one...how to correct this to make the code works with all timings executed properly?

Comment: Use `Promises` instead, and `await` each one

Answer (score 0):

Why not just set them like this?

```
setTimeout('one', 6000);
setTimeout('two', 6500);
setTimeout('three', 10500);
setTimeout('four', 12500);
```

Alternatively, you can use callbacks or promises. See an example of how to accomplish this at my other answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51779367/javascript-stop-execution-untill-delay-is-over/51779412#51779412).

Answer (score 0):

If you pull the times into an array, you have a lot of options.

For example, you can make a recursive function that shifts a value from the array and then calls itself until there are no more times:

```js
function go(times) {
  if (times.length < 1) return
  let t = times.shift()
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("calling timeout", t)
    go(times)
  }, t)
}
const delays = [6000, 500, 4000, 2000]
go(delays)
```

You could also use something like `reduce` to progressively add the previous time to the current time to make all the timeOuts at once with the correct times:

```js
[6000, 500, 4000, 2000].reduce((total, time) => {
  setTimeout(() => console.log(time), total + time)
  return total+time
}, 0)
```

You can also wrap the timeout in a promise and use `async/await`:

```js
const timeout = (time) =>  new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(()=>resolve(time), time))

async function go(times) {
  for (time of times){
    console.log(await timeout(time))
  }
}

go([6000, 500, 4000, 2000])
```